# How to bypass simple ISP block?

Tags: networking, ipv6, isp

***Background***: My ISP (under the influence of our precious government) recently started blocking public web-sites for no particular reason.

***Problem***: My guess is that ISP is using DPI to rule out which pages to show and which to not. If I send request with curl like normal web browser does that:

```
curl -L -g -4 -v  --header "Host: blocked.site" blocked.site
```

ISP redirects me to their fancy page with a message that I should not visit this site.

***Possible solution***: I discovered that modifying "Host" request header, I can easily access this site, for example:

```
curl -L -g -4 -v  --header "Host: blocked.site." blocked.site
```

or just add couple spaces after domain name.
I thought that I could resolve this issue by using IPV6 protocol (some ISP's don't check traffic on them), my ISP doesn't support it, so I had to create tunnel (6in4). But it seems like ISP is inspecting all packets for Host headers and blocks them no matter what protocol I use.

The "dot solution" suits good for me, how can I automate it on router (OpenWrt)? so I don't have manually modify headers on every dives in my network. And is it possible to do something with IPV6? because it looks better to me than modifying headers.

Comment: HTTPS with HSTS should avoid this I think, but for HTTP you would probably need the flexibility of something like PFSense.

Comment: Why not simply use Tor and/or privoxy or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried it, but [privoxy](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/proxy.privoxy) should work using [filters](http://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/filter-file.html).

Comment: Thanks, I installed it on the router, and now I'm just changing request headers only for blocked sites. Everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a proxy service like others have posted, or use a non-proxy site to 'fool' your ISP:

1. Go to [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/)
2. In the left box, type the link you want to go to.
3. In the right box, select a language (like Spanish) that's *not* english (Or the main language of the site)
4. Click the link in the right box
5. On the new page, click "Original" near the top right

This is a workaround that acts like a proxy server, without the ISP knowing it's a proxy. You should now be able to view the website with ease!

Hope this helps!

Comment: Privoxy is a different type of proxy - it runs on YOUR hardware rather then paying for a provider or being a "proxy service", and it is designed to modify pages to make them more to your liking based on how you configure/script it.

Comment: Ok, but in another question he was saying it wouldn't work. So I gave him a different solution.